# How to transition to "hidden" in javascript and css when toggling

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-animate, css-transitions

I'm trying to make a div appear when a certain button is pressed and have it toggle between the class .hidden (which hides the div). I've tried to animate this by adding a transition but for some reason the fact that it's being hidden somehow disrupts that. In short, I want to know if there is a way to animate the transition between hidden and visible states.

```js
var main = function() {

  $("#myMenu").css("height", window.innerHeight);
  $("#myMenu").css("width", window.innerWidth);

}


$(document).ready(main);
```

```css
.toggle {
  font-size: 20px;
  margin: 20px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 100;
}
.hidden {
  visibility: none;
  display: none;
}
.menu {
  background-color: red;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!--contains hamburger-->
<div class="toggle">
  <a id="tButton" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="toggleNav()">&#9776;</a>
</div>

<!--actual mobile menu-->
<div id="myMenu" class="menu hidden">
  <ul>
    <li><a onclick="toggleNav()">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li><a onclick="toggleNav()">Events</a>
    </li>
    <li><a onclick="toggleNav()">About</a>
    </li>
    <li><a onclick="toggleNav()">Volunteer</a>
    </li>
    <li><a onclick="toggleNav()">Contact</a>
    </li>

  </ul>

</div>

<script>
  function toggleNav() {
    $("#myMenu").toggleClass("hidden");
    if ($("#myMenu").hasClass("hidden")) {
      $("#tButton").text(String.fromCharCode(9776));

    } else {
      $("#tButton").text(String.fromCharCode(10005));
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: fadeToggle --- slideToggle ...

Comment: That works, but what if I want the menu to start as a hidden?

Comment: start it as 'display:none' on CSS

Answer (score 1):

Try this out.

```
if ($("#myMenu").hasClass("hidden")) {
      $("#tButton").text(String.fromCharCode(9776));

       $("#myMenu").fadeIn()
        $("#myMenu").removeClass('hidden');
    } else {
      $("#myMenu").addClass('hidden');
         $("#myMenu").fadeOut();
      $("#tButton").text(String.fromCharCode(10005));
    }
```

Full Demo

```js
var main = function() {

  $("#myMenu").css("height", window.innerHeight);
  $("#myMenu").css("width", window.innerWidth);

}


$(document).ready(main);
```

```css
.toggle {
  font-size: 20px;
  margin: 20px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 100;
}
.hidden {
  visibility: none;
  display: none;
}
.menu {
  background-color: red;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!--contains hamburger-->
<div class="toggle">
  <a id="tButton" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="toggleNav()">&#9776;</a>
</div>

<!--actual mobile menu-->
<div id="myMenu" class="menu hidden">
  <ul>
    <li><a onclick="toggleNav()">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li><a onclick="toggleNav()">Events</a>
    </li>
    <li><a onclick="toggleNav()">About</a>
    </li>
    <li><a onclick="toggleNav()">Volunteer</a>
    </li>
    <li><a onclick="toggleNav()">Contact</a>
    </li>

  </ul>

</div>

<script>
  function toggleNav() {
  
    if ($("#myMenu").hasClass("hidden")) {
      $("#tButton").text(String.fromCharCode(9776));
     
       $("#myMenu").fadeIn();
        $("#myMenu").removeClass('hidden');
    } else {
      $("#myMenu").addClass('hidden');
         $("#myMenu").fadeOut();
      $("#tButton").text(String.fromCharCode(10005));
    }
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are already using jQuery, you can let the library do the heavy lifting for you.

**[`fadeIn()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadein/), [`fadeOut()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/) and [`fadeToggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadetoggle/) will help you:**

```js
$('#my-div').hide();

function show() {
  $('#my-div').fadeToggle();
}
```

```css
#my-div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button onclick='show()'>Toggle</button>
<div id='my-div'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using jQuery but for some reason, you're trying to do it manually.
You have multiple jQuery functions that do that for you.

```
$("#myMenu").toggle();
```

This alone will hide and show your element with a default animation.
You can customize it further with at http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

You also have other methods such as [fadeToggle](http://api.jquery.com/fadetoggle/) (or individually with [fadeIn](http://api.jquery.com/fadein/) and [fadeOut](http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/)) and [slideToggle](http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/) methods you can use.
Including the `hide` and `show` method.. that either hide or show your element... (so no need for a `.hidden` css class)